# Solr query delete by Id work for XML but not for Json

Tags: solr

I am trying to delete index in Solr. When i run XML query it deletes, but if i try JSON query it gives success message but it does not delete and weirdly it increase count by 1 by adding new row:

```
XML:

    <delete><query>id:5a048bb5-f661-4517-a55e-e15e663c2cd7</query></delete>

JSON:

{
    "delete": {
        "query": "id:5a048bb5-f661-4517-a55e-e15e663c2cd7"
    }
}
```

Comment: To which endpoint are you sending the JSON queries?

Comment: try the "curl -X POST "http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionName/update?commit=true" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{"delete": {"id":"id:5a048bb5-f661-4517-a55e-e15e663c2cd7"}}' "